# Using a VPS as front end proxy

Tags: proxy, openvpn, vps, ddos

I run a shell host that many users share which gets frequently DDoS'd (at least once every other month).  So I have come up with a plan to peer all traffic with a VPS, so that it appears to everyone from the internet that all traffic in and out is actually coming from the VPS.  In this way I can hopefully get the benefit of a VPS service that provides a serious level of DDoS filtering/protection without just null routing the IP at the first sign of trouble.

So I have set up a VPS with 2 IPs, one with ssh access for me to administer, and one to use forwarding all traffic.  I was thinking of setting up an OpenVPN connection between the two hosts, but am unsure if this is the best option.  I wouldn't use GRE because I'd prefer the peer traffic to be encrypted.

Beyond this, I am a little hazy on how to set up the routes on the VPS side to make all traffic forward through like a proxy while maintaining only the one external IP address.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of some documentation or perhaps have some thoughts or personal experiences?

Comment: VPS providers who provide "a serious level of DDoS filtering/protection" are pretty rare, in my experience. I suspect this plan won't work as well as you think it will.

Comment: I didn't understand well what are you going to proxy there. Is it shell login? is the service attacked ssh?

Comment: is your server connected directly to the internet?

Comment: @ceejayoz what about RamNode with the $5 a month IP that gets routed through Staminus?  They claim up to 50Gbps throughput.

Comment: @ignivs we run a lot of services, it is a lot of users with shell access who can run any service they want in the higher port ranges, and I also run email/http/etc for them.

We've had all different kinds of DDoS happen.  TCP SYN, UDP reflection, Chargen, IP Fragmentation, TCP NULL, etc.

Comment: @Rob-d yes, my origin host is connected to the internet.

Comment: disable user/password logins and use public/private keypairs